# running a django project for localhost or over internet using apache and modwsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, web-deployment

I'm trying to run a django(1.4 or later) project so that it can be accessed over internet. I have apache and mod-wsgi installed. merely entering IP in browser gives the "It works" output. At /etc/apache2/sites-available/ location I created a file example.com which has

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/workspace/project/project/wsgi.py

    <Directory /home/user/workspace/project/project/>
        Options None
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and, the /home/user/workspace/project/project/wsgi.py has the following:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

# import sys    
# sys.path.append('~/workspace/project/project/')
# import django.core.handlers.wsgi
# application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

have run:

```
sudo a2ensite example.com
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

and when I run example.com from browser it says, "Oops! Google Chrome could not find example.com".
I even have tried adding the project root in python path. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: do you have dns set up pointing from domain to your server ip?

Comment: I've not done anything related to dns setup. I was not aware even. I have found out now that it's related to `/etc/resolv.conf`? When I open the file with intention to add **nameserver xxx.com**, I see msg not to add things by hand as they will be over-written next time. Could you be li'l detailed please.